# one way anova - is this possible

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics, self-learning

**What is the value of F with a distribution having a between-groups sum of squares of 3500 and a within-groups sum of squares of 320?**

I think this question is impossible because you need to know the degrees of freedom right?

The only thing I could think that it is not referring to the f statistic. Does the quotient of the sum of squares have any meaning?

Is this just a duff question.

Comment: You can state $F$ without the degrees of freedom.  But you may find it difficult to test whether it is significant.

Comment: how, when F=MSR/MSE